# iphone UISCrollView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

Using a UIScrollView with a view containing som textviews and button. In viewDidLoad setting:

```
_myscrolview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

I looks fine in poratraite but in landscape I am unable to scroll to the top for typing in textViews?

Tried setting in "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation"

```
_myscrolview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

With or without "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation"... it only scrolls a bit, but unable to get to the top?

Thanks 
Regards
Christian

Comment: What is the relationship between _myscrolview and self.view? Is self.view a subview of _myscrollview?

Comment: self.view is the view containing the scrollableView _myscrolview. This is to make the scrollable height the same as the view in portrait. Should probably not set anything in "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation". But its the same anyways. I am thinking of making two views in the xib file and have one for landscape and one for portrait - any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: But even having two view in xib - I am probably going to run into the keyboard overlapping the textviews without any scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `_myscrolview.frame` is changed due to the device rotation.

```
_myscrolview.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

And every subview inside `_myscrolview` probably needs to be re-oriented as well, Their width and height may need to be set to the landscape width.

After sub views inside `_myscrolview` is resized, you can then calculate the `contentSize` by:

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;

for (UIView *oneView in _myscrolview.subviews) {
  contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, oneView.frame);
}

_myscrolview.contentSize = contentRect.size;
```